# RoR Devise: Sign in with username OR email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

What's the best way to enable users to log in with their email address OR their username? I am using warden + devise for authentication. I think it probably won't be too hard to do it but i guess i need some advice here on where to put all the stuff that is needed. Perhaps devise already provides this feature? Like in the config/initializers/devise.rb you would write:

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :email, :username ]
```

To require both username AND email for signing in. But i really want to have only one field for both username and email and require only one of them. I'll just visualize that with some ASCII art, it should look something like this in the view:

```
Username or Email:
[____________________]

Password:
[____________________]

[Sign In]
```

Comment: Wouldn't the title be 'RoR Devise: Sign in with username OR email'?

Comment: are the usernames guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: @Moox: you are right, sorry for the typo
@scunliffe: yes, the usernames are unique

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I have found a solution for the problem. I'm not quite satisfied with it (I'd rather have a way to specify this in the initializer), but it works for now. In the user model I added the following method:

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(conditions={})
  find_by(username: conditions[:email]) || find_by(email: conditions[:email])
end
```

As @sguha and @Chetan have pointed out, [another great resource is available on the official devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address).

Comment: The blog entry linked in this post is now dead

Comment: It's also detailed on the devise wiki https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address

Comment: The link @sguha posted is the way to go.  It even creates a virtual attribute login which is a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: The method above should probably be re-written as: `self.find_by(username: conditions[:email]) || self.find_by(email: conditions[:email])`

Comment: @KevinSylvestre hash syntax is better, I agree. But I think find_by will raise an exception instead of returning nil when nothing is found. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @PatrickOscity `find_by!` and `find` raise an exception but `find_by` returns `nil`.

Comment: Ah right, but `find` does, I mixed that up. Thanks for your suggestions! I also removed the `self`.

Answer (score 28):

From their Wiki — [How To: Allow users to sign in using their username or email address](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address).

Comment: this solution is better as it is documented on devise wiki

Answer (score 9):

```
def self.find_for_authentication(conditions)
  conditions = ["username = ? or email = ?", conditions[authentication_keys.first], conditions[authentication_keys.first]]
  # raise StandardError, conditions.inspect
  super
end
```

[Use their example!](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign_in-using-their-username-or-email-address)

Comment: using their example, shouldn't it be `def self.find_for_database_authentication(conditions)` ?

Comment: btw, with their example, using rails 3.0.0.beta4 i got a `NoMethodError in Devise/sessionsController#create undefined method `assert_valid_keys' for ["username = ? or email = ?", "xxx", "xxx"]:Array`, that's why i used my own solution

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you already added username field and add username to attr_accessible.
Create a login virtual attribute in Users

1) Add login as an attr_accessor

```
# Virtual attribute for authenticating by either username or email
# This is in addition to a real persisted field like 'username'
attr_accessor :login
```

2) Add login to attr_accessible

```
attr_accessible :login
```

Tell Devise to use :login in the authentication_keys

Modify config/initializers/devise.rb to have:

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :login ]
```

Overwrite Devise’s find_for_database_authentication method in Users

```
# Overrides the devise method find_for_authentication
# Allow users to Sign In using their username or email address
def self.find_for_authentication(conditions)
  login = conditions.delete(:login)
  where(conditions).where(["username = :value OR email = :value", { :value => login }]).first
end
```

Update your views
Make sure you have the Devise views in your project so that you can customize them

> ```
> remove <%= f.label :email %>
> remove <%= f.email_field :email %>
> add <%= f.label :login %>   
> add <%= f.text_field :login %>
> ```

Comment: While modifying config/initializers/devise.rb file be cautious with the occurrence of :email.
Example:
config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]
config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]
For the above cases we have to handle manually

Answer (score 2):

https://gist.github.com/867932 : One solution for everything. Sign in, forgot password, confirmation, unlock instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Platforma Tec (devise author) has posted a solution to their github wiki which uses an underlying Warden authentication strategy rather than plugging into the Controller:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address

(An earlier answer had a broken link, which I believe was intended to link to this resource.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **MongoDB** (with MongoId), you need to query differently:

```
  def self.find_for_database_authentication(conditions={})
    self.any_of({name: conditions[:email]},{email: conditions[:email]}).limit(1).first
  end
```

just so it will be somewhere online.

Answer (score 1):

With **squeel** gem you can do:

```
  def self.find_for_authentication(conditions={})
    self.where{(email == conditions[:email]) | (username == conditions[:email])}.first
  end
```

Comment: No need to use the squeel gem, you could also do this like this: `User.where("username = :email OR email = :email", email: "user@site.com")`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Rails solution which refactors @padde's answer. It uses ActiveRecord's find_by to simplify the calls, ensures there's only one call based on the regex, and also supports numeric IDs if you want to allow that (useful for scripts/APIs). The regex for email is as simple as it needs to be in this context; just checking for the presence of an @ as I assume your username validtor doesn't allow @ characters.

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(conditions={})
  email = conditions[:email]
  if email =~ /@/ 
    self.find_by_email(email)
  elsif email.to_s =~ /\A[0-9]+\z/
    self.find(Integer(email))
  else
    self.find_by_username(email])
  end
end
```

Like the wiki and @aku's answer, I'd also recommend making a new :login parameter using attr_accessible and authentication_keys instead of using :email here. (I kept it as :email in the example to show the quick fix.)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote like this and it works out. Don't know if it's "ugly fix", but if I'll come up with a a better solution I'll let you know...

```
 def self.authenticate(email, password)
   user = find_by_email(email) ||
     username = find_by_username(email)
   if user && user.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
     user
   else
     nil
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a quick hack for this, to avoid changing any devise specific code and use it for my specific scenario (I particularly use it for an API where mobile apps can create users on the server).

I have added a before_filter to all the devise controllers where if username is being passed, I generate an email from the username ("#{params[:user][:username]}@mycustomdomain.com") and save the user. For all other calls as well, I generate the email based on same logic. My before_filter looks like this:

```
def generate_email_for_username
    return if(!params[:user][:email].blank? || params[:user][:username].blank?)
    params[:user][:email] = "#{params[:user][:username]}@mycustomdomain.com"
end
```

I am also saving username in the users table, so I know that users with email ending in @mycustomdomain.com were created using username.