# How do you configure devise to accept either an email OR a username to login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Out of the box, the [devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki) gem asks for a user's email address and uses that to sign in (authenticate).

This railscast, ["Customizing Devise"](http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise), describes clearly how one can authenticate with a username in lieu of an email.  How would one configure devise to try to authenticate against two different columns, either username OR email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need define the method find_for_database_authentication(conditions). By example, with monogid I do that :

```
  def self.find_for_database_authentication(conditions)
    self.where({ :login => conditions[:login] }).first || self.where({ :email => conditions[:login] }).first
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, sorry, I didn't google sufficiently.  There's an answer on the devise wiki: ["Log in using login or mail"](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Log-in-using-login-or-mail)

Also, this question was already asked and answered on stackoverflow here: ["Sign in with username OR email"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997179/ror-devise-sign-in-with-username-or-email)

There's a further [blog discussioon](http://www.howradical.com/getting-devise-to-accept-a-username-or-email) that uses the self.find_for_authentication method which is Rails 2.x compatible.