# Ruby gem to quickly make a login validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, validation, savon

I have a webservice -somewhere- to validate passwords and stuff, and a module using SAVON that makes the corresponding questions in order to verify someone. The thing is, I don't have the login to work with my module. I was trying to use DEVISE to work with it, but I can't figure out how to do it yet.

**Does anybody know a good gem that can work and take advantage of SAVON in order to make login validations?**

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any gem that works with SAVON but you can use [find_for_database_authentication](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L92) of Devise

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(conditions)
    where('users.rut = ?', conditions[:rut]).first
end
```

For more detail, see [RoR Devise: Sign in with username OR email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997179/ror-devise-sign-in-with-username-or-email)