# Does devise work with multiple email_id with same account ??

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, authentication, devise

[Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is a fantastic gem available for basic or omniauth authentication sign_up and other things like sessions maintenance, resend confirmation password etc .

But is it possible using devise to map multiple email addresses to same user ?

Like I have 3,4 email ids such as

1. sahil@abc.com
2. sahil@xyz.com
3. sahil@mno.com

**Use Case and Example**

I have already registered with my first email id  i.e. `sahil@abc.com` using an automated system and account is created. But i always prefer to use my other email_id i.e. `sahil@xyz.com`. So, i want to build a system where user can login using any one of the above email adresses with the same/different password. But there should be one single account for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what i exactly needed [RoR Devise: Sign in with username OR email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997179/ror-devise-sign-in-with-username-or-email)

```
  def self.find_for_database_authentication(conditions={})
    (self.find_by_email(conditions[:email])) || (AuthorizedEmail.confirmed.find_by_email(conditions[:email]).user if AuthorizedEmail.confirmed.find_by_email(conditions[:email]).present?)
  end
```

What it does is :

1. Firstly tries to find the user record for authentication by searching with email id.
2. If it gets the record it returns the record else we go to next part.
3. It finds in the authorised emails table if there exists any validated and confirmed email in the table. If there is such an entry, it tries to find the user related to that particular authorised email and returns that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

- you've one email field
- you have other emails stored somewhere

You could tell Devise that [you allow login based on different fields](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address).

Answer (score 1):

I think the cooler way is to give a try to override the 'authentication_keys' method, as it [allows you to define the keys](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address).

But how ever , following link has a [working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997179/ror-devise-sign-in-with-username-or-email) :)

HTH