# How to log in with e-mail or username on one login form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How would one who has multiple user models with Devise log in with either username or email to one login form with Devise then redirect to a custom page?

I'm able to get the username/e-mail login to work and be redirected to their own custom page but my problem is with the unified log in.

Comment: You should read it first [devise wiki How-Tos](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-Tos)

Comment: Wonder why I was downvoted? ...Tough crowd. I've read through all those how-tos but nothing explains how to get the unified log in to work when using two separate Devise models

Answer (score 0):

This is probably duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997179/ror-devise-sign-in-with-username-or-email).

You could add this method to your user model

```html
def self.find_for_database_authentication(conditions={})
  find_by(username: conditions[:email]) || find_by(email: conditions[:email])
end
```

or you could see how to allow users [sign in using their username or email address](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address) from the [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki)

Comment: I edited my initial post with more details on my issue. I'm able to get the username/e-mail login to work and be redirected to their own custom page but my problem is with the unified log in.