# Send devise confirmation instructions using SMS or email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Hi I have used devise for the authentication purpose and also made few changes in it such I have provided **sign in using both email and mobile number**. Refereed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997179/ror-devise-sign-in-with-username-or-email).

Here is my code

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(conditions={})
    find_by(mobile_number: conditions[:email]) || find_by(email: conditions[:email])
  end
```

I am using **confirmable** module for sending confirmation instructions and they are working fine for email.

Now if user doesn't enter this email (only enters the mobile number) then he has to send the SMS **(Confirmation instruction in SMS)**.

So I have following doubts

- `How can I achieve this functionality?`
- `How can I generate the same confirmation link for the same.`

**EDIT (I tried following solutions for generating confirmation link)**

As I have to send the confirmation link in SMS also, so I tried to generate the given link using following

```
http://localhost:3000/admin_users/confirmation?confirmation_token=#{@user.confirmation_token}"
```

it generates the follwing type of link

```
http://localhost:3000/admin_users/confirmation?confirmation_token=00b2880c9662c65dc6d276db08532ea42d4333e6b7d2357d036cb9233eed41e8
```

when I tired to use this link it gives me **Confirmation token is invalid** error. After searching I found [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2615). So how can I generate the confirmation link out side the devise scope.

Answer (score -1):

As for sending the instructions via SMS you might want to take a look at [tropo](https://www.tropo.com/) service or [restcomm](http://www.restcomm.com) if you want to setup your on server.
Tropo is particularly easy to use, you will need a small deposit (like $10) to enable the SMS sending feature.

Regarding the generation of the url, you might have to create a controller that extends `Devise::ConfirmationsController` and override the `create` method to add the logic to check for the existence of email or phone number and react properly.