# Rails 5: Devise login with username or email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I followed the tutorial on setting up devise to use an username or email and everything is working fine. My problem lies in the layout, is there any way to display the form this way?

I want to have only one field for both username and email and require only one of them.

```
Username or Email:
[____________________]

Password:
[____________________]

[Sign In]
```

What would the actual code look like, since I never used mutliple attributes on a field. Probably something like this, is this even possible ?

```
...
<%= f.text_field [:username, :email], class: "form-control" %>
```

Comment: seems to be a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997179/ror-devise-sign-in-with-username-or-email?rq=1

Comment: checkout Devise wiki https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this from the HTML form. You'll need to add code to the User model to take the input and determine whether it matches an existing username or email. Fortunately, [the Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign_in-using-their-username-or-email-address) has a detailed solution for what you need to do.